# How can I bold only one word, after I change the text content with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, text

I am stuck trying to bold a single word after i change the text content in HTML via JavaScript.

Here is my code:

```js
document.getElementById('par3').textContent = "I <b>love</b> JS";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Homework05</title>
</head>

<body>

  <p id="par1">Unchanged Paragraph</p>
  <p id="par2">Unchanged Paragraph</p>
  <p id="par3">Unchanged Paragraph</p>
  <p id="par4">Unchanged Paragraph</p>
  <p id="par5">Unchanged Paragraph</p>




  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Somehow, the  tags are not rendered. Is there any specific escape characters for this? Or this is more complex thing to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `innerHTML`. `textContent` will escape your string.

```js
document.getElementById('par3').innerHTML= "I <b>love</b> JS";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Homework05</title>
</head>

<body>

  <p id="par1">Unchanged Paragraph</p>
  <p id="par2">Unchanged Paragraph</p>
  <p id="par3">Unchanged Paragraph</p>
  <p id="par4">Unchanged Paragraph</p>
  <p id="par5">Unchanged Paragraph</p>




  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tnx a lot, u saved me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
use innerHTML other then textContent or
```

choose the word and define it to string var then use *string*.bold() method.